# AWS ECS container instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have tried to launch an ECS container instance using Ansible EC2 module.

My playbook is as follows.

```
- name: Launch ECS Container Instance
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ ec2_keyname }}"
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-ca01d8ca
    wait: yes
    group: "{{ ec2_security_group }}"
    region: ap-northeast-1
    exact_count: 1
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ec2_subnet_id }}"
    count_tag:
      docker-registry: 1
    instance_profile_name: ecsInstanceRole
    instance_tags:
      Name: ECS_docker-registry
      docker-registry: 1
    assign_public_ip: yes
```

As a result, two instances launched; one of them is configured as I intend, but another has following tags that I don't intend to set.

- aws:autoscaling:groupName
- aws:cloudformation:logical-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-name

In addition, I can find these two instances on ECS dashboard.

[image]

But its only visible for the cluster "default", and invisible for other clusters.

---

**What I really want to do** is;

- Launch a ECS container instance
- Register the container instance to a cluster

It's better if I can do the process above with aws-cli, but first I should understand the strange behaviour of container instances and do manually.

Comment: The problem also happens when I launch a instance manually from EC2 dashboard, instead of Ansible.

Answer (score 4):

To register an EC2 container instance in a ECS Cluster you have a few options:

1. Use special **amazon-ecs-optimized** AMI to manually launch EC2 instance with custom user data with `awscli` or AWS Console (read more about [Launching an Amazon ECS Container Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html)):

   ```
       #!/bin/bash    
       echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
   ```
2. Use [AWS OpsWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) and create **ECS Cluster layer** since [AWS OpsWorks Supports Managing Amazon ECS Container Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/07/aws-opsworks-supports-managing-amazon-ecs-container-instances/). In this case OpsWoks will any EC2 instance within a layer to work with particular ECS Cluster.

There are few limitations:

1. Each OpsWorks Stack can have only one ECS Cluster layer
2. Each EC2 instance can be assign only to one ECS Cluster

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an EC2 instance to an ECS cluster manually:

1. Create a file in /etc/ecs/ecs.config with this line:

   ```
   ECS_CLUSTER={{ name }}
   ```

   Where {{ name }} is the cluster name you want.
2. Install the ecs agent (package name is "ecs-init") and start it.

The instance will create the cluster if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking into using `user_data` field of the ec2 module.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

You will need to have the following in `ecs.config` before the ecs agent starts up.

> #!/bin/bash
>       echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config